# Hidden Wire Detector, Oscilloscope Measurement

Tags: bjt

We have a hidden wiring detector device[image]

I used 2SC1815 transistors and the value of R was 1K0. My antenna was made of 300 mm length copper wire with diameter 0.3 mm. I've measured its inductance - it is about 2 uH.

When we connect the oscilloscope to the base of the transistor, and put the earth on the emitter, we get an oscillogram with a cut off top.
She cuts about 0.47 volts
Why is that? What's the matter?
[image]

Comment: "to the base of the transistor": there's three transistors in your schematic. Which one?

Comment: to the first transistor from the antenna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could zoom in on the top part of the waveform, you will see it is a LOGARITHM of a current, that current induced by electric fields in the laboratory around you, coupled to your 300mm wire.

The scope (probe) Rin of 10,000,000 ohms is also diverting part of the (Efield displacement) current.

Assume a parallel-plate model

- C = Eo * Er * area / distance

Assume this becomes 9e-12 pFmeter * (300mm * 0.3mm) / 300mm, or

Capacitance =

- 9e-12 * 0.3mm == 27e-15 farads.

The current will be I = C * dVdT

- I = 27e-15 * [(for 60Hz) 220 volts * 1.414 * 377 radian/seconds]

or about

- I = 27e-15 * 160,000 volts per second

==

- 27 * 1.6 (in our pretend precision) * e-15 * e+5
- I = 40 * 1e-10 amps or about 4 nanoAmps

In the real world, with your 300mm wire being the ONLY piece of metal around to gather_in those Efield flux lines, you could use the equation for

- plate_to_wire coupling

which increases the Capacitance by 2 * PI * natural_log (wire_width / separation).

For a 0.3mm wire, located (2.718 ^ 6.28 ) ratio away, the coupling is about the same for parallel_plate versus plate_wire coupling.

If you hold the wire **NEAR** a power cable, you'll have much more than parallel_plate_predicted coupling.

===============================

You might ask "since we don't know the exact metal topology, how do we know which equations to use?"

You will discover the capacitive coupling equations --- parallel-plate, plate-to-wire, wire-to-wire --- are dramatically different in form and in the predicted coupling, **BUT** the predictions only differ about 10:1 at most.

Thus using a (not exact but not far wrong) bit of physics is the key to having a very useful **ESTIMATE** of the capacitance, thus of the available (displacement) current.

Your 3_transistor experiment lets you approach Electric-fields, and realize they can be approximated, instead of being ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You're applying a rising voltage to the base-emitter diode of a bijunction transistor.

What you observe is the expected behaviour of a diode in this situation. Look up "diode I/V diagram":

Current through the diode is exponential to voltage, and at some point, it really conducts very well, so that the base would have to source much current to significantly increase the voltage.

However, where should that current come from? Your antenna isn't a perfect voltage source, so it simply can't increase the current any further.

The problem is made worse by you attaching an oscilloscope: Now that draws away another part of the already very small current.

So, this is all working as expected! If you need a more sensitive amplifier, you'll have to build a better amplifier than what looks like to be a low-gain silicon general purpose transistor based one without proper biasing.

Another word on your reference: Youtube really has a **terrible** ratio of bad electronics videos to good ones. Maybe look for another source of information. This isn't a great circuit, and a very similar one was in my first exam about transistors and diodes with the question "Why doesn't this work very well as amplifier for alternating currents". It was an entry-level question.

Comment: Marcus, thank you for your answer. To be honest, we are ordinary students from Russia and this is our project, we are first-year students. The teacher does not give us peace and does not want to give us a grade, although the device is working. He torments us with questions. Could you help us with another question about the resistor? We have a resistor installed not as in the diagram, but on the collector of the first transistor and it is rated 1000 Ohms, you can not explain to us what function the resistor performs in this place and how you can argue that it is at 1000 Ohms. Thanks

Comment: Ok, to get this straight, you built this from a youtube video without understanding it, and now you complain about your teacher asking you questions about this? I'd say your teacher is doing exactly the right thing, forcing you to understand what you've built, because it's his job to teach understanding, not teaching copying of circuits from somewhere else.

Comment: Also, no, let's not ask new questions in the comments. If you have another question about your device, ask a new question on this site, add exactly the schematic you've built, not something else, and ask clearly.